# webapp django_setup

Tags: python, google-app-engine

From [SDK 1.x.x Release Notes](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.5.0_-_May_10,_2011) it said that `Users can provide Django settings to be loaded in webapp's django_setup.`. Does anybody know what is it about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell this looks like something that was supposed to go out with 1.5.0, rolled back again due to some regressions found - but the release notes were not updated :|

Comment: I am not sure where did you get this info. `django_setup` is still present in `webapp.__init__` in SDK 1.6.2.

Comment: The release notes item you mentioned is from the 1.5.0 release, the _django_setup has been in there a while longer. Also, the release notes item referred to something other than this function. This is something you can look up by browsing the publicly available SDK repository. And where did I get the info about the roll back? I'm on the App Engine team so I have access to what went on behind the scenes :P

Comment: Say hello to App Engine team then. :) It still would be nice if this item is removed from release notes.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but it kind of felt like not the right thing to do (rewriting even incorrect "historic" notes). I rather tend to keep the mistake publicly documented (here) and hope that it's good enough.